# Remove the first lines till the occurence of a regular expression in a column

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I have some lines that I get in order using following

```
grep ENSG00000006114 File | sort -V 
chr17   35874900    35879174    ABCD0000006114:I25  -
chr17   35874901    35879174    ABCD0000006114:I25  -
chr17   35875548    35875671    ABCD0000006114:E27  -
chr17   35875672    35877289    ABCD0000006114:I26  -
chr17   35877290    35877445    ABCD0000006114:E26  -
chr17   35877446    35877932    ABCD0000006114:I25  -
```

However I want to delete the first rows that contain ':I' in the first row until I get ':E' for that I have been trying something like

```
grep ENSG00000006114 File | sort -V | awk '{if ($4 ~ /:I/ && NR==1) next};1'
```

However there might be more than one occurrences as in the above case for the first few rows, so how do I exclude rows containing :I until the first :E occurs in first row such that my final outcome would be:

```
   chr17   35875548    35875671    ABCD0000006114:E27  -
   chr17   35875672    35877289    ABCD0000006114:I26  -
   chr17   35877290    35877445    ABCD0000006114:E26  -
   chr17   35877446    35877932    ABCD0000006114:I25  -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
grep ENSG00000006114 File | sort -V |
awk 'p==1 && $4 ~ /:E/{p=2} !p && $4 ~ /:I/{p=1} p==1{next} 1'

chr17   35875548    35875671    ABCD0000006114:E27  -
chr17   35875672    35877289    ABCD0000006114:I26  -
chr17   35877290    35877445    ABCD0000006114:E26  -
chr17   35877446    35877932    ABCD0000006114:I25  -
```

- When `p==0` && `$4` matches `:I` then we set `p=1`
- While `p==1` we skip that record and move to next
- When `p==1` && `$4` matches `:E` then we set `p=2` thus allowing remaining records to print.

Comment: Thanks a lot (for the explanation as well) ..worked !

Comment: That's far more complicated than it has to be, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/39559531/1745001. Might be time for coffee ;-).

Comment: Appears bit more involved because OP wants to only skip block from first `:I` to next `:E` in `$4`. If there is no `:I` then we need not skip lines until `:E`

Comment: @anubhava, Good one. You give generic solution that works even when **E** preceeds **I**.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the grep+sort are useful in that order due to your input file being enormous, all you need from awk is:

```
grep ENSG00000006114 File | sort -V | awk '$4~/:E/{f=1} f'
```

and if the file isn't huge you can lose the grep:

```
sort -V File | awk '!/ENSG00000006114/{next} $4~/:E/{f=1} f'
```

Comment: You give most elegant and simple solution that matches OP's data  (because **E** doesn't preceed **I** anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You could also just redirect it right back to `grep`:

```
$ grep ENSG00000006114 File | sort -V  | grep -A 10000000000000000 :E
chr17   35875548    35875671    ABCD0000006114:E27  -
chr17   35875672    35877289    ABCD0000006114:I26  -
chr17   35877290    35877445    ABCD0000006114:E26  -
chr17   35877446    35877932    ABCD0000006114:I25  -
```